# How to parse log file with python regex and key value dictionary containing IP and numeric value

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, dictionary, logging

I want to parse this (https://bpaste.net/raw/477b79a86b42) log file containing the output in specific format of number & IP next to it. I want to fetch the IP and do sum total for total number of connections made, For example in the syntax below:

```
[0;32m192.168.1.34 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
2
192.168.1.97
5
192.168.1.152
3
192.168.2.108
11
192.168.2.144
[0m
[0;32m192.168.1.18 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
2
192.168.1.97
3
192.168.1.152
14
192.168.2.108
7
192.168.2.144
[0m
[0;32m192.168.2.137 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
5
192.168.1.97
10
192.168.1.152
53
192.168.2.108
6
192.168.2.144
[0m
[0;32m192.168.1.96 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
```

The input to script should be read as file, store the number and IP, then output should be IP & sum, For. e.g. 192.168.97 : 84 , 192.168.1.152 :66

In the python script below I want to take advantage of collections.Counter, regex and key value dictionary to iterate, My initial version of code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python



import os
from collections import Counter
import re
import urllib


def main():

    # read the content
    parse_content = urllib.urlopen(
        'https://bpaste.net/raw/477b79a86b42').read()

    count = Counter()



    for line in parse_content:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print count
        # r'(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'
        if re.search(r'/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$', line):
            print line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

can I use loop over two sequences, fetch ip and store in first sequence and then sum in other, If yes then how should I write the logic, my initial thought on python pseudo-code is:

```
conn_n = ['2', '5', '3']
ip_seq = ['192.168.1.97', '192.168.1.152', '192.168.1.108']
dict = {"conn_n":"ip_seq"}

for key,val in d.items():
      if line.startswith('['):
      print re.findall(r'/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$/', line)
      ....
      ....
      print("{} = {}".format(key, val))
```

I would really appreciate some help on what path to take to tackle this problem should I use lists and loop through it or dictionaries?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: not sure what the context is around your code, but I would suggest playing around with Logstash which might be a better fit for the job :) it's basically designed for filtering/organizing log info and has really impressive [regex capabilities](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use regular expressions for this at all. Just pay attention to the nature of your lines. I chose to create generators to make it somewhat easier to understand what's happening:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import collections
import ssl    # See note in logfile_lines, below
import urllib

LOGFILE = r'https://bpaste.net/raw/477b79a86b42'

def logfile_lines(url):

    # NOTE: This business of `_create_unverified_context` is because I 
    # don't have py2.7 set up correctly w/r/t ssl. I normally use py3.
    # If you're stuck using 2.7, go ahead and get your certificate verification 
    # working properly!

    logfile = urllib.urlopen(url, context=ssl._create_unverified_context())

    for line in logfile:
        if ' |' in line:
            continue

        if not line[0].isdigit():
            continue

        yield line.strip()

def count_address_pairs(url):

    logiter = iter(logfile_lines(url))

    for count, address in zip(logiter, logiter):
        yield (int(count), address)

counts = collections.Counter()

for cnt, addr in count_address_pairs(LOGFILE):
    counts[addr] += cnt

print(counts)
```

Output looks pretty simple:

```
$ ./test.py
Counter({'192.168.2.108': 138, '192.168.2.144': 87, '192.168.1.97': 84, '192.168.1.152': 66})
```

Comment: Austin, thanks your solution is simple and yet powerful approach to problem, can you explain why you used ssl verification for this piece, What does it do?

Comment: The URL is `https` so there has to be an SSL component. But I don't have things set up on my machine for python2.7, so urlopen fails with an SSL error. That's why I had to create a non-verifying context, so it would ignore the certificate from the server during the HTTPS connection. It has nothing to do with the problem, it's just an artifact of my laptop environment.

Comment: Thanks @austin-hastings I got what purpose it serves. Lots of thanks for the help. I truly appreciate, lot to learn from you.